# is transforming (tf) a pointcloud faster than transforming the points one by one

Tags: ros, transforms, tf2, transform, gpu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have about 600 points with the same time stamp and frame id. I am transforming them all one by one by multiplying the transform pre-obtained by lookupTransform with the point:

```
t = lookupTransform()
for ( point in points )
  btVector3 p = point
  btVector3 q = t*p
  point = q
```

This is taking quite some time, which is a problem because these are points from the velodyne so I have to do it again and again for millions of them.

I am wondering if there would be an advantage in throwing them all in a point cloud and transforming the whole cloud at once.

I saw that the tf::TransformListener::transfromPointCloud function is using boost::numeric::ublas in the background, which construct one big matrix with all the points and multiplies it with the transform.
see http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/c++/transform__listener_8cpp_source.html#l00288

I also saw that joq's code for his velodyne driver is using pcl_ros to transform the cloud, which ends up calling pcl::transformPointCloud that can be seen here:
http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/transforms_8hpp_source.html#l00042

At the end, you can't beat the fact that you have to multiply each point by the transform matrix, so it's only a question of computational efficiency... Which would be more efficient then: pcl_ros or ublas, and why?

Of course I will know if I experiment all of those solutions, but I am hoping that someone will save me that pain...

Also I have been thinking about GPUs these days. Is there a GPU implementation of this? Would that make sense? I guess it would for large enough point clouds...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52664/is-transforming-(tf)-a-pointcloud-faster-than-transforming-the-points-one-by-one/) by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1001 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I gave it a go and used tf::TransformListener::transfromPointCloud and it turned out to be much much faster (CPU usage went from hogging a core to 10%). I haven't tried pcl::transformPointCloud yet, but I guess I will, because that would be interesting to know which one is faster.

I am a bit puzzled though. I am copying my points to a point cloud, then they get copied to a ublas matrix. This matrix is then multiplied by the transform. Then points are copied back to a point cloud and back to my data format. So first of all there are 2 copy operations (but in my own implementation I also had to copy to a btVector3 back and forth ...). Then the number of mathematical operations is still the same, isn't it: the 600 points still have to be multiplied by the transform. So either ublas is exceptionally well optimized, or my implementation was really crappy.

EDIT:
Since then, I have switched from diamondback to fuerte. I noticed that the implementation of tf::TransformListener::transfromPointCloud has changed, starting from electric. It is now transforming all the points one by one. See the following API links for a comparison:

- [diamondback](http://ros.org/doc/diamondback/api/tf/html/c++/transform__listener_8cpp_source.html#l00288)
- [fuerte](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/tf/html/c++/transform__listener_8cpp_source.html#l00266)  (electric to groovy)

I haven't thoroughly timed them, but it seems that it's still doing a good job at it.

---

Originally posted by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) with karma: 1001 on 2013-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-22**:
There are all kinds of crazy optimizations that can be done in serious numerical libraries. No sane programmer would do them in a simple loop.

**Comment by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) on 2013-03-04**:
Have you checked the performance of tf::TransformListener::transfromPointCloud versus pcl::transformPointCloud? I assume they are about equal, but would be interested in the results nevertheless :-)

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2013-03-04**:
no I haven't tried

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only way to be sure is to code it up and measure the time.

Since it seems likely, that would probably be worth the effort.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2